# cannot find module after npm install

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, azure, npm

I'm running Node.js on an Ubuntu server through Microsoft Azure. I have a `package.json` that looks like this:

```
{
  "author"       : "Coop",
  "name"         : "app-framework",
  "main"         : "server.js",
  "version"      : "0.0.0",
  "private"      : true,
  "dependencies" : {
    "express"            : "~4.7.2",
    "morgan"             : "~1.5.0",
    "bcrypt"             : "~0.8.0",
    "forever"            : "~0.13.0",
    "mongodb"            : "~1.4.25",
    "mongoose"           : "~3.6.2",
    "nodemailer"         : "~1.3.0",
    "body-parser"        : "~1.9.2",
    "method-override"    : "~2.3.0",
    "express-session"    : "~1.9.3",
    "connect-mongostore" : "~0.1.4",
    "nodemailer-sendgrid-transport" : "~0.1.0"
  }
}
```

Now when I run sudo `npm install`, it tries to install the modules. However, if I then try and run my application with `node server.js`, I discover that some dependencies of my modules did not install.

I'm having to go through a long list and manually install lots of modules. Why is this happening and how can I just get everything to install correctly from the `package.json`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out this was to do with the version of MongoDB. I just changed the version to 1.3.19 and everything was happy.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running **npm install** on Azure? Try **npm install --production**

Comment: Yes npm install on azure. I think it may be a problem with the version of MongoDB now. Something to do with that and compatibility with Mongoose.